# Primefaces tooltip positioning in datatable

Tags: xhtml, primefaces

We are implementing primefaces tooltip on datatable.
But tooltip postining is away from the datable row.

```
<p:tooltip targetPosition="bottomLeft" Delay="0" showDelay="0">
<h:outputText value="#{label.lockTime}"
style="font-weight:bold" />
<h:outputText value=": #{cert.lockTime}" />
<p:spacer width="1" height="10" />
<h:outputText value="#{cert.label} " style="font-weight:bold" />
<h:outputText value=": #{cert.userDetails}" />
</p:tooltip>
```

Comment: Tooltip is not supported within the Primefaces data table at this time.  I believe the Primefaces Extensions project has a dataTable capable tooltip component, or you can look at this question and implement an overlaypanel hack instead, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980155/jsf-2-0-primefaces-2-x-tooltip-for-datatable-row

Answer (score 1):

You try this

```
<p:tooltip />
<p:dataTable var="var" ........>
    <p:column headerText="Market" >
        <h:outputText value=" #{var.market}" title=" #{var.market}" 
                      style="display:block;">
        </h:outputText>             
     </p:column> 
     <p:column headerText="Value" >
        <h:outputText value=" #{var.value}" title=" #{var.value}" 
                      style="display:block;">
        </h:outputText>             
     </p:column> 

</p:dataTable>
```

I hope It will work.