# How to show tool tip for row in data table in prime faces?

Tags: user-interface, xhtml, primefaces, datatable, tooltip

How can i display a ToolTip (Title) for one row in data table

I'm using prime faces 3.4.2

Please give me a solution.

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980155/jsf-2-0-primefaces-2-x-tooltip-for-datatable-row/9988296#9988296

Comment: no. Let me check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf). You can specify p:row element and add tooltip for it.